# Как сделать красивый текст с помощью php?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Требуется разделить слова и цифры с учётом знаков препинания, например:

```
5бананов, апельсинов6, 2ёлки3палки.
```

перевести в:

```
5 бананов, апельсинов 6, 2 ёлки 3 палки.
```

И ещё такой вариант:

```
дом35б  , корпус.3,квартира7.
```

Перевести в:

```
дом 35б, копус 3, квартира 7.
```

Как это реализовать на *php*?

Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Comment: А где ваш вариант? И что в нем не работает?

Comment: У меня такой вариант `preg_replace('/([^\x80-\xFF\/])/i', ' $1 ', $str)`, но его не достаточно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сорри, что js, а не php, зато в одну регулярку работает:

```
["5бананов, апельсинов6, 2ёлки3палки.", "дом35б  , корпус.3,квартира7."].map(function(s) {
  return s.replace(/\s*(,)\s*|(\d)\s*(?=[а-яё]{2})|([а-яё])(?:\.|\s*)(?=\d)/ig, "$1$2$3 ");
});
// ["5 бананов, апельсинов 6, 2 ёлки 3 палки.", "дом 35б, корпус 3, квартира 7."]
```

Думаю, для php регулярка тоже должна подойти.

Comment: Да, работает на php.

Answer (score 1):

Так как у @binliz не красивая строка получается ;), вот мой вариант:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$pattern = array("/(\d+)(\p{L})/u", "/(\p{L})(\d+)/u");
$replacement ="$1 $2";
$string = "5бананов, апельсинов6, 2ёлки3палки.";
var_dump($string);
$string = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
var_dump($string);
```

В один проход у меня не получилось сделать преобразование, скрипт делает его за два раза. Сначала ставится пробел на границе "цифра-буква", затем на границе "буква-цифра".

Для

```
5бананов, апельсинов6, 2ёлки3палки.
```

получил

```
5 бананов, апельсинов 6, 2 ёлки 3 палки.
```

Для (например)

```
544б55ан1123анов, апельсинов6777, 2ёлки3палки888.
```

получил

```
544 б 55 ан 1123 анов, апельсинов 6777, 2 ёлки 3 палки 888.
```

Comment: Спасибо за хороший ответ! Не могли бы Вы мне ещё разок помочь (поправил вопрос)?

Answer (score 1):

@Visman, нужно было отказаться от захвата символов и использовать позиционные проверки для нулевой длины общего совпадения:

```
$string = "5бананов, апельсинов6, 2ёлки3палки.";
$re = "/(?<=\\d)(?=\\p{L})|(?<=\\p{L})(?=\\d)/u";
$string = preg_replace( $re, " ", $string );
```

Тогда бы Вы уложились в одну регулярку.

Comment: У меня до сих пор туго с этими хитростями.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $string = '5бананов';
echo intval($string).' '.$strval($string);
```

Comment: Не подойдёт для варианта "2ёлки3палки"

Answer (score 0):

Может как-то так:

```
$pattern ="/(\d+)/";
$replacement =" $1 ";
$string = "5бананов, апельсинов6, 2ёлки3палки.";
$string = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
var_dump($string);
```

Comment: Не красивая строка получает.

Comment: А красотой никто и не старался заниматься, тут не решают задачи за людей, а предлагают варианты решения на сколько я помню.